Average Model of Buck Converter
I am trying to understand average model of Buck Converter for Peak Current Mode Control Topology. Below is a snapshot taken from the Christophe Basso Webpage https://powersimtof.com/Spice.htm, from file “PWM Switch LTspice: Mark Dimattina”: https://powersimtof.com/Downloads/LTSpice/PWM-CM2-MD2.zip

Above encircled block is power stage and below is the expanded view of the same.

Now I can understand the power stage main equation and all which is highlighted in yellow but my question is what are these above yellow encircled area I am not sure why do we need those complex equation. Can anyone please help here?
One more when I match the average model result with measurement loop response result there is a exact match at max/higher load but there is a slight mismatch at light/min load. I am not able to figure it why there is a shift at min/light load.
